# Fraction latex for regular expression

Tags: regex

I want pattern for fraction regex  in latex  to matching  these example.

1. `\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}   (fraction overlap fraction).`
2. `\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}.`

Full example problem :

```
\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{11}} - \sqrt{12}
```

*Copied from comment:*

fraction pattern detect full match and groups. such as:

```
\\frac\s*{((?!\\frac{).*?)}{((?!\\frac{).*?)}
```

(not correct).

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is your problem? For me it far from being clear. You should precise your question et give examples of your current attempts.

Comment: fraction pattern detect full match  and groups. such as: \\frac\s*{((?!\\frac{).*?)}{((?!\\frac{).*?)} (not correct).

Comment: Try `\\frac\s*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})({(?:[^{}]++|(?2))*})`, see https://regex101.com/r/o5agQw/1